Uploading base64 encoded documents in ContentVersion via SOAP API
We have an export of the ContentVersion object, containing the VersionData base64 encoded file. I have rebuilt the ContentVersion object to only contain the fields: Title, Description, PathOnClient,VersionData, and ContentLocation.
The VersionData contains the base64 encoded value returned in the VersionData field in the export.
Is it possible to insert these ContentVersion's into another org, using the base64 encoded value as the VersionData field? We are using dataloader for this and the SOAP API.
Unfortunately we are unable to use the Data Export tool to export objects and files.
I have already tried uploading the updated ContentVersion csv via dataloader, but it is being seen as an invalid csv. I am sure its valid as the csv libraries in my scripts are seeing it as valid.
Many thanks
